# is there a blender/food processor combo still made?

Tags: food-processing

A long long time ago I had one--I think it was a sunbeam. one base unit worked for both the blender and the food processor[.](https://www.roboticreviews.us/food-processor/) I could really use that now, but haven't had any luck finding one.
it doesn't have to be a sunbeam, just one which uses one base for two functions.
help?

Comment: Where are you? In the UK Kenwood still made a food processor with a blender to go on top when I last looked but I don't recognise the sunbeam brand so I suspect you're elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

Yes, several companies are selling these blender/food processor combos. A quick search found [this Oster](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072KSYMLB) and [this Cuisinart](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017US77P0), as well as several others.